# Why does load-theme reset the custom-theme-load-path?

Tags: elisp, themes

For some reason, I need to manually update the `custom-theme-load-path` list after every update of a theme like `smart-mode-line` or `leuven-theme`. Looking for a solution, I came across [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15381087/1219634) post.  Here is the solution from that post (with slight modification):

```
;; Ensure that the custom-theme-load-path has all the theme paths added
;; Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15381087/1219634
(require 'dash)
  (require 's)
  (-each
      (-map
       (lambda (item)
         (format (concat elpa-dir "/%s") item))
       (-filter
        (lambda (item)
          (or (s-contains? "theme" item)
              (s-contains? "smart-mode-line" item)))
        (directory-files elpa-dir)))
    (lambda (item)
      (add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path item)))
```

The above snippet works great and it updates `custom-theme-load-path`. The catch is that every time I load a theme using `load-theme`, the `custom-theme-load-path` resets to the value set by *Customize*. I have verified this behavior by putting `(message "%s" custom-theme-load-path)` before and after the call to `(load-theme ..)`.

**How can I permanently set the value of `custom-theme-load-path` so that `load-theme` cannot reset its value?**

Here is a workaround I use to avoid this issue (but I'd like to understand why this is happening):

- I have wrapped the above snippet in a function called `update-custom-theme-load-path`.
- I call that function right before I call `(load-theme 'leuven t)`

Comment: To clarify: `custom-theme-load-path` is set in Customize.  When you update (via `package.el`) either `leuven` or `smart-mode-line`, those packages are no longer on `custom-theme-load-path`?

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin Yes, those paths don't get auto updated even when I install through `package.el`. I used to manually update the path till I found the above snippet.

Comment: Do you have a call to `package-initialize` in your `init-file`?  And/or could you test running `package-initialize` after updating the theme, but before loading it?

Comment: I do have `(package-initialize)`. I call it before requiring any of the themes. I also tried `C-x C-e` on that just now with the themes updated; but that did not update `custom-theme-load-path`. I `load` [this](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-packages.el) before requiring any theme/package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The Short Answer

You should **not** customize the `custom-theme-load-path` variable in the *Customize* interface.
So call `M-x customize-variable RET custom-theme-load-path` and ask
to erase customizations (and save changes).

If you want to configure a custom theme directory beyond that which
packages automatically add, customize the
[`custom-theme-directory`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Var/custom-theme-directory)
variable instead. That is exactly what this variable is for.

---

### The Long Answer

Any customizations made through the *Customize* interface are
reapplied whenever a theme changes. That’s due to 2 reasons:

1. Themes are not just about faces, they’re about variables too.
2. And the user customizations should always supersede the
   customizations applied by themes.

Thus, whenever a new theme is applied, the user customizations must be
reapplied on top of it. Since your customization contains the
`custom-theme-load-path` variable, themes are unable to add themselves
to it.

That’s probably why the `custom-theme-directory` variable was created.
This one is safe to customize, because it’s only yours (themes won’t
touch it).

Comment: I am under that assumption that `custom-theme-directory` can contain just one directory. Isn't that true?

Comment: I didn't need to set the `custom-theme-directory`. But I simply erased the customization of `custom-theme-load-path` and now the value set to this list in my init.el stick! Thanks!

Comment: @kaushalmodi Yes, the custom-theme-directory variable is only needed if you want a directory beyond the automatically added ones AND you want to use the customize interface.

Comment: It's almost as though `package.el` needs to have it's own `package-theme-directory` that it can add files to, so that installations don't worry about customize overwriting them.

Comment: Thanks everyone. In closing I'd like to add that I don't need the snippet I have in the question any more and I can successfully add my forked version of `zenburn` using `(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path (concat user-emacs-directory "/from-git/zenburn-emacs/"))`; I simply need to erase the customization of that list from custom.el in the events I save the customizations using the Customize interface. I don't find the `custom-theme-directory` variable very useful as it can hold just one directory.

Comment: `custom-theme-directory` being one directory is still useful because themes are just individual files. Not so good for version control, but symlinks fix that.

Comment: *If it is true* that users should not customize option `custom-theme-load-path` using Customize then it **should not be a user option**. If this is really the case (dunno - I don't use custom themes), then please *file an Emacs bug*: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. User options are **by definition customizable using Customize**, and that should in fact be the primary way of modifying them (that, or using equivalent `customize-*` or `custom-*` functions). Or if your answer applies only to this use case, then please make that clear - it looks like you are advising not to customize the option in general.

Comment: @Drew Yes, I _am_ advising against the use of the customize interface for this variable. And yes, it's a bug. But it's part if a deeper bug with the customize interface---one which I'm sure they're aware of. Namely, the interface leads to problems when both the user and a package add values to a list. If the user does it first, any further changes will get reverted upon load-theme. If the package does it first, these changes will get saved too when the user makes his changes, and when the package is uninstalled it could leave behind references to itself.

Comment: If the admonition is just to **not both** (1) use the Customize UI and (2) modify outside of the Customize UI, then of course that is general (and there is no bug, IMO). That wasn't clear (to me). Even then, there is not *necessarily* a problem, if users **use `custom*` functions to do the modifying** and they also **save** such "outside Customize" changes. What is asking for trouble is both (1) changing outside Customize **without** using `custom*` functions and (2) using Customize. But none of this is special to this variable, AFAICT.

Comment: @Drew Yes, none of this is special to this variable. This variable is just a very common instance of this overall conflict.

Comment: @Malabarba Do you think this info ( "You should not customize the custom-theme-load-path variable in the Customize interface.") should be in the `custom-theme-load-path` variable doc-string too? I faced this problem a year ago, and people are still [facing the same today](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/17137/115).

Comment: @kaushalmodi I think it'd be best if this variable weren't a defcustom at all. I'll bring that up on the dev list.