# Emacs Can't Find Theme File

Tags: themes

```el
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d")
(load-theme 'sanityinc-solarized-dark-theme)
```

I have these two lines in my .emacs file, and those theme files in the listed directory, yet emacs still does not detect the theme file.

I've seen other threads with similar issues, but none have worked for me so far, particularly with using package.el

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are installing the theme using the `package.el`, you should not set the `custom-theme-load-path`.

All you need to do is:

- Install the theme from the emacs package manager as explained in the [theme's instructions](https://github.com/purcell/color-theme-sanityinc-solarized#via-elpa).
- Put `(load-theme 'sanityinc-solarized-dark)` in your `.emacs`.
- The first time you load the theme (and the first time after each update of that theme), emacs will ask if you consider that theme to be safe and you hit `y` or `yes`.

### How to install this theme step-by-step from an `emacs -Q` session

1. Eval below in the *scratch* buffer

   `(require 'package)`

   `(add-to-list 'package-archives
            '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))`
2. `M-x package-list-archives`.
3. Find the theme package you want to install, `color-theme-sanityinc-solarized` in this case.
4. **Important Step!** `M-x package-initialize` or eval `(package-initialize)`.
5. `M-x customize-themes` and select the check box in front of `sanityinc-solarized-dark` or `sanityinc-solarized-light`.
6. Done.

### How to load this theme automatically when you restart emacs

Here is a minimum-working `test-load-theme.el` file to load this theme automatically. You need to have the theme installed using the package manager first!

```el
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
(load-theme 'sanityinc-solarized-dark t)
```

Save above in `~/.emacs.d/test-load-theme.el`. It is a good convention to put emacs related stuff in `~/.emacs.d`.

Start a fresh emacs session while loading just the above file:

```
\emacs -Q -l ~/.emacs.d/test-load-theme.el
```

*[Related emacs.SE question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2112/115)*

Comment: It says that the theme is not found. I installed the color-theme-sanityinc-solarized-2.25.

That's the folder name. Should I just write the name without the 2.25?

Comment: I have updated my answer on how to install this theme in a fresh `emacs -Q` session. Suggestions: (1) **Erase** the customization for `custom-theme-load-path` (2) You are probably missing `(package-initialize)` in your .emacs file.

Comment: Also the theme name is `sanityinc-solarized-dark`, not `sanityinc-solarized-dark-theme`.

Comment: Awesome! So what was the problem?

Comment: I wasn't too sure. I think I had a different theme name

Comment: I had to add a theme name and a t) at the end, instead of just a parentheses

Comment: The third argument `t` is not mandatory. Having it there prevents emacs from asking you if you consider the theme as safe and want to load it.

Comment: It probably was a theme name then. I managed to install the packages, but it didn't work. But then I found someone with the correct theme name, and it worked (:

Comment: It does not work - it says "theme is not found"

Comment: @Draif It would help us help you if you put in more information.. What step exactly doesn't work? Also it would be better to post a new question with detailed steps to reproduce your problem.