# Emacs won't load theme installed from MELPA

Tags: init-file, themes, package-repositories

I just installed the seti-theme from MELPA and no errors occurred. Than I ran M-x load-theme and after a few questions nothing would hapen and emacs would throw the following error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/matthias/.emacs':

error: Unable to find theme file for `seti'

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

After I did the same a *second time in a session* the theme would appear without any errors.

I tried to add the theme to my .emacs( http://pastebin.com/Gk7gH3dT ) with:
(load-theme 'seti), which doesn't work either.

```
emacs --debug-init
```

results in:

```
    Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Unable to find theme file for `seti'")
  signal(error ("Unable to find theme file for `seti'"))
  error("Unable to find theme file for `%s'" seti)
  load-theme(seti)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/matthias/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 113
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/matthias/.emacs" "/home/matthias/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262   \306=\203\307\310Q\202; \311=\204\307\312Q\202;\313\307\314\315#\203*\316\202;\313\307\314\317#\203:\320\nB\321\202;\316\322\323\322\211#\210\322=\203a\324\325\326\307\327Q!\"\323\322\211#\210\322=\203`\210\203\243\330!\331\232\203\243\332!\211\333P\334!\203}\211\202\210\334!\203\207\202\210\314\262\203\241\335\"\203\237\336\337#\210\340\341!\210\266\f?\205\260\314\323\342\322\211#)\262\207" [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs" windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" (initialization "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'") "~/_emacs" t load expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7 "\n\n(fn)"]()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

The theme I had installed manually works fine.

Comment: Sounds like the directory that contains the  library defining that theme is not in your `load-path`. Put it in your `load-path`, using `add-to-list`. And then `require` the library.

Comment: ok that fixed it. I thought installing using packages would do that automatically.

Comment: I believe that the solution of [this question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2112/115) asked a while back here on emacs.SE might resolve the problem for you to. If so, let me know if marking this question as duplicate seems fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked:

```
(when (>= emacs-major-version 24)
  (require 'package)
  (add-to-list
   'package-archives
   '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
   t)
  (package-initialize)
;; set theme
(load-theme 'seti t)
```

In combination with the steps explained here:

[Why does load-theme reset the custom-theme-load-path?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2112/115)

and what is written in the comments below.

Comment: [You should **not** customize the `custom-theme-load-path` variable in the Customize interface](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2113/115).

Comment: ok. So what would be the correct line to add the theme? I can't seem to figure it out?

Comment: You need to completely erase the `custom-theme-load-path` variable from your customizations, delete and reinstall your theme, put `(load-theme 'THEME-NAME t)` in your emacs config and restart emacs. For your case, it will be `(load-theme 'seti t)`. You must also have `(package-initialize)` in the very beginning of your emacs config that will take care of loading the themes installed using the package manager.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now it worked. There is so much information online for old emacs versions. It gets confusing very  fast. Thanks

Comment: As you use emacs more, you will learn to ask emacs itself the right questions.. to learn even more emacs :) The best non-confusing help you can get is from within emacs. Type `C-h i g`, then `(emacs) Package Installation` and hit `RET`. Do `C-h i h` to learn navigating info nodes in emacs.

Comment: `C-h r` (mnemonic: **r** stands for emacs manual **r**eference) will take you to the Emacs info manual. It's contents in HTML form are mirrored on https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html. But again, to get help specific to your emacs version, you should always rely on the info manual that comes packaged with your installed emacs (`C-h r`).

Comment: You can accept your own answer after, I believe, 48 hours since you posted the answer.

Comment: Adding `(package-initialize)` to the top of my emacs config is what worked for me.

Comment: Your snippet is missing a closing parenthesis.