# Leuven theme cause emacsclient not to start

Tags: themes

I have a hint for leuven which look quite nice, especially the presentation in orgmode, so I've installed with from the package manager.

Since I can't find it in `M-x cusomize-themes`, I have tried to load it with `(load-theme 'leuven)` in my `.emacs`, and this cause emacs -daemon failing to start...

Has anyone ever encountered that problem with leuven theme before ?

Thank you

Comment: emacsclient is not starting because you probably have a yes or no prompt blocking it. Try using `(load-theme 'leuven :no-confirm)` instead. Also note that do **not** set the `customize-theme-load-path` variable using the Customize interface -- [Source](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2113/115).

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue before. My understanding is `emacs --daemon` doesn't try to create a frame. But the `theme` or `face` configuration try to wait until the frame is created to apply it.

My current solution is (not perfect):

Add you configuration to `after-make-frame-functions` hook.

For example:

```
(defun ec-theme-cfg ()
    ;; put your configuration here)

(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions #'ec-theme-cfg)
```

After that change, `emacs --daemon` can start properly and `emacsclient` works well.

But there's an issue with this solution, after run `emacs --daemon`, I have to at least create an Emacs frame (`emacsclient -c`) before I can use `emacsclient -t` from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to make sure it does appear in your `customize-themes`menu, rather than loading it manually via your init file. Leuven appear sin my list of themes (although you can see below I do not use it as default)

Is you can see in the image below, there is the tip at the top

> Theme files are named *-theme.el in `custom-theme-load-path'.

[image]

So make sure you have the file saved on that path. To get help with this, try `C-h v` then `custom-theme-load-path`, which will show you the current path(s) defined and gives hints on how to customise it.

Comment: The path is present in `custom-theme-load-path` and leuven-theme.el is there...

Comment: It was already, or have you just added the path and file? Restart emacs so the paths are reloaded. Otherwise, without knowing more, I cannot guess as to why customize-themes isn't listing it! Maybe Look inside the file itself for a clue. Alternatively, just place the file in your .emacs.d/ in a folder of your choice, then add that to custom-theme-load-path. Try that anyway, if nothing else works.

Comment: Ok I've decided to clean everything and reinstall emacs and now I can see it. While trying to solve my problem, I have learnt more about theme, custom vs color and now I am scared about custom theme !
I just have apply leuven without saving, and after restarting it's still here !

So to keep emacs clean I guess I don't wan't to try themes and choose THE theme, am I right ?
How do you manage your themes ?

Comment: After you applied leuven, if it stays there after a restart then I imagine a line was added to your .emacs file, somewhere towards the bottom in `custom-set-variables`. I haven't played with themes for a while, I just switch between the two that I use manaually, but I do have something [like this](https://libraries.io/emacs/cycle-themes) installed so I have a shortcut to swap between themes too. `color-theme` is also a nice package for managing themes, but I didn't find a way to include themes that aren't already contained within that package. I use the `zero-dark` and `leuven` themes.

Comment: @DexterMorgan FYI for [color-theme](http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/) You can just do: `(add-to-list 'load-path ".emacs.d/plugins/color-theme/themes/")` before `(color-theme-initialize)` to point the package to a subdirectory full of additional themes.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with emacs-daemon and themes for a while. I bind this to f5 and just execute it after I open my first frame. Without doing this spacemacs-dark doesn't appear quite right.

```
(defun startup-load ()
  "Reload things because Emacs daemon has strange behavior with frames and themes."
  (interactive)
  (resize-frame-small)
  (load-theme 'spacemacs-dark t)
  (theme-setup-set-faces)
  (resize-frame-left))
```