# Customize variable: custom-theme-load-path[no match]

Tags: themes

1. I followed instruction [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2112/why-does-load-theme-reset-the-custom-theme-load-path) to erase customization. however, it returns [no-match]. am i doing anything wrong here?

[image]

2. The reason that I was trying to erase the custom-theme-load-path is that I failed to load color theme from .init file,  in the following way. any hint on why it failed to load the **solarized** theme? Any help is appreciated!

> having the following piece in a file `general-settings.el`

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path (make-plugin-path "color-theme-solarized"))
(load-theme 'solarized 1)
```

> and then `(require 'general-settings)` in my .init file
>
> make-plugin-path is defined as below:

```
(defun make-plugin-path (plugin)
  (expand-file-name
   (concat plugin-path plugin)))
```

> plugin-path is a defined variable

Comment: Your usage of `expand-file-name` looks strange. It should rather look like `(expand-file-name plugin plugin-path)`. But, we cannot definitively comment on that without knowing the value of `plugin-path`. Note furthermore, you should not ask multiple question in one posting here. BTW, your first question is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the [question you have linked](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2112/2370) lead to the [decision](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2112/why-does-load-theme-reset-the-custom-theme-load-path#comment25570_2113) to demote `custom-theme-load-path` from `defcustom` to `defvar` in Emacs 25.0.90.

For that reason it is no longer customizable by `customize`.

The corresponding commit was [995b69918b with title "custom.el (custom-theme-load-path): Demote to defvar"](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/995b69918bddb58536b5d09d2127179314e1fffb).

I cite here the comment of that commit:

> `custom-theme-load-path` was a defcustom, but it shouldn't be for the
>   same reason that `load-path` shouldn't.  Setting it via the customize
>   interface is a trap for the user.
>
> Installed themes commonly add themselves to this variable, which means
>   its value is not fit for being saved (it will permanently remember dirs
>   that don't exist anymore).
>
> This is aggravated by the fact that Emacs always applies the 'user'
>   theme on top of any theme that's loaded, since this will apply the old
>   variable value and remove any new directories that had been recently
>   added by themes themselves.
>
> Not to mention, we already have `custom-theme-directory`, which is safe
>   to customize.